# Problems with Toolbar when using DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, drawerlayout

When using the `Toolbar` with `DrawerLayout` the Toolbar seems to fill all the activity:

- title with `gravity:center_vertical for Toolbar` is located in the middle of the screen
- background that is set for the `Toolbar` is set for all activity

  In the screenshot below is set for the toolbar `gravity: top`. And I can't align the title in the center of the `Toolbar`, because when i set `gravity: center_vertical` Title moves to the center of the screen

*https://gyazo.com/e8d35f12753a657436e0e0f626a01a91*

**toolbar.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar_action"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/toolbar"
android:gravity="top"
app:titleTextColor="@color/title">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/drawer_item_pressed"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/drawer_menu_background" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java** - part where I set Toolbar

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_action);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.burger);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

I can assume that the problem in Layouts?

Comment: Your `<DrawerLayout>` should have only two direct children; the drawer `View` – which is your `<ListView>`, in this case – and the main content `View`. You need to somehow combine the toolbar `<include>` and the `<FrameLayout>` into one `ViewGroup`, depending on your design requirements; e.g., put both inside a vertical `<LinearLayout>`.

Comment: This is the right decision, thank you!